# Trying to call a method and redirect after

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to call this post method and then redirect to the place the link goes to, but I'm getting tripped up by the routing. The method gets called, but that's it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<%= link_to image_tag('notifications3.fw.png', size: "32x32", title: "Notifications", class: 'cr'), activities_path %>
```

My routes

```
resources :activities, path: 'notifications'
post 'activities/read_all_notifications'
```

The js

```
    $(document).on('click', '.cr', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return $.ajax('/activities/read_all_notifications', {
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          return xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").attr("content"));
        },
        cache: false
      });
    });
```

The methods

```
def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order(created_at: :desc)
                                .where(recipient_id: current_user.id, 
                                recipient_type: 'User')
end

def read_all_notifications
    PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).update_all(:read => true)
    render nothing: true
end
```

The log

```
    Started POST "/activities/read_all_notifications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-19 11:55:51 -0700
    Processing by ActivitiesController#read_all_notifications as JSON
      User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
      SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "activities" SET "read" = 't' WHERE "activities"."recipient_id" = 3
      Rendered text template (1.5ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
```

Comment: How do you know the method gets called?

Comment: It shows up in the log.

Comment: You're making an AJAX call, so if you need to do any redirection that's the responsibility of that JavaScript code. Rails-level redirects will be ignored. Why not `render(json: { redirect: '/...' })` and return the target destination, then have the JavaScript pick up on that and redirect accordingly?

Comment: Why ajax if you want to redirect?

Comment: Sorry, still new to programming. I want the link to go to one page, but before that just call the read_all_notifications

Comment: I added  render(json: { redirect: '/notifications' }) but its still staying on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing link to

```
<%= link_to image_tag('notifications3.fw.png', size: "32x32", title: "Notifications", class: 'cr'), 'activities/read_all_notifications', method: :post %>
```

and handle it in html (remove javascript)

```
# And in the controller 

def read_all_notifications
  PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).update_all(:read => true)
  redirect_to :activities
end
```

Note, you can change the routes to

```
resources :activities, path: 'notifications' do
  collection do 
     post :read_all
  end
end
```

Then, in the view you can use a method (`read_all_notifications_path`) to generate the url.  This is more flexible and better in the long run.

```
<%= link_to image_tag('notifications3.fw.png', size: "32x32", title: "Notifications", class: 'cr'), read_all_notifications_path, method: :post %>
```

Comment: Should the read_all route be read_all_notifications to match up with the action?

Comment: Also, now its rendering the notifications page twice

Comment: The action would change to 'read_all' if you did this.  And the method would be `read_all_activities_path`.  You can always look at routes with `rake routes`.  Also, you can add an `:as => :notifications` attribute to the route and refer to them as notifications everywhere.  Then `read_all_notifications_path` would work.